# Sentential Logic. Reasoning.

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

can anybody critique, and if necessary, correct, my reasoning in the following translation?

c.  Either Alice has a dog and Carol has a cat, or Bob has a dog and Carol does not have a cat.

This is two compound conjunctive statements connected by an “or.” So, the main logical operator is “or,” which is symbolized as “∨.” This statement as a whole is a compound disjunctive statement. It is not an inclusive disjunctive because it cannot be the case that Carol both has and does not have a cat; it cannot be the case, for example, that Alice can have a dog in the case that Carol does not have a dog, so whether Alice or Bob are dog owners is wholly contingent upon whether or not Carol has a cat.

On the left side, we have two atomic statements. The first says that “Alice has a dog” and is symbolized by A. The second atomic statement says that Carol has a cat, which is symbolized by C. These two left hand atomic statements, when read in conjunction, are symbolized as (A  ∧ B).

On the right side, we similarly have two atomic statements that work in conjunction to form one compound statement: “Bob has a dog and Carol does not have a cat.” 
This is symbolized as (B ∧ C).

Since we have outlined how the different components of the statements are symbolized, when we add them all together as a whole, we have (A  ∧ B) ∨ (B ∧ C).

Note: It is possible that both Alice and Bob have dogs, respectively, i.e., “Alice has a dog, Bob has a dog, and Carol has a cat,” or “Bob has a dog and Alice has a dog, but alice does not have a cat.” Thus the reason that this disjunctive compound statement as a whole is non-inclusive is wholly contigent upon Carol’s cat ownership status.

Comment: It's $(A \wedge C) \vee (B \wedge \neg C)$.  Your final note is correct.

Comment: IMO, you need not justify why this is an inclusive disjunction. You could write it as an exclusive disjunction, and by simplification you can easily show that this is in fact an inclusive or.